# Problems animating an NSImageView/NSView with or without constraints

Tags: cocoa, animation, constraints, autolayout, nsview

I'm trying to do some very simple view animation in a window (xib) that is using AutoLayout and I'm getting some very unpredictable results. Obviously the auto layout engine is doing some things under the hood and I don't know how to fix it.

To start with, my window has a grid of 3x3 NSImageViews that are set to NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown. After setting the content compression to 10, the views do the right thing when the window is resized...everything stays in the right place and in the correct proportions. A nice 3x3 grid of images.

When the user clicks on a view, I want the view to takeover the entire window and fade out the other views. Then, when touched again, animate back to it's original position.

To keep things something simple, constraint-wise, I decided to leave all the NSImageViews in place and create another one on top of the touched view and use it to animate. That's the problem one.

I've tried animating that view 2 ways: by animating the constraints, and by not using constraints on that view and just animate it's frame. Either way, I get crazy results.

Here's the code:

**Using Constraints**

```
- (void) moveToFullView:(NSInteger)which
{
self.soloIndex = which;
NSImageView *tmpView = self.imageviews[which];

// create a view directly on top of the touched view
self.soloView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:tmpView.frame];
[self.soloView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.soloView.image = tmpView.image;
self.soloView.imageScaling = NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown;

// without this, the window changes size in moveBackFromFullView
[self.soloView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:10 forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal];
[self.soloView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:10 forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical];

[self.view addSubview:self.soloView];

// create constraints with animatable constants    
CGFloat leftSpace = tmpView.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat topSpace = tmpView.frame.origin.y;
CGFloat width =  tmpView.frame.size.width - self.view.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat height = tmpView.frame.size.height - self.view.bounds.size.height;

self.soloView.leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.soloView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:leftSpace];

self.soloView.topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.soloView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.view
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:topSpace];

self.soloView.widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.soloView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:width];

self.soloView.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.soloView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:height];

[self.view addConstraint:self.soloView.leftConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:self.soloView.topConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:self.soloView.widthConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:self.soloView.heightConstraint];
[self.view layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];

// animate the view to occupy the entire self.view
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
    context.duration = 0.75;

    // fade out the other views for now
    for(NSImageView *p in self.imageviews){
        p.alphaValue = 0;
    }

    // these values should make the soloView in the same place and size as the self.view
    self.soloView.leftConstraint.constant = 0;
    self.soloView.topConstraint.constant = 0;
    self.soloView.widthConstraint.constant = 0;
    self.soloView.heightConstraint.constant = 0;

    [self.view layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
} completionHandler:nil];
}



- (void) moveBackFromFullView
{
// this is where the solo view should animate back to
NSRect destR = [self.imageviews[self.soloIndex] frame];


CGFloat leftSpace = destR.origin.x;
CGFloat topSpace = destR.origin.y;
CGFloat width =  destR.size.width - self.view.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat height = destR.size.height - self.view.bounds.size.height;

[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
    context.duration = 0.75;

    for(NSImageView *p in self.imageviews){
        p.alphaValue = 1.00;
    }

    self.soloView.leftConstraint.constant = leftSpace;
    self.soloView.topConstraint.constant = topSpace;
    self.soloView.widthConstraint.constant = width;
    self.soloView.heightConstraint.constant = height;

    [self.view layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
} completionHandler:^{
    [self.soloView removeFromSuperview];
    self.soloView = nil;
}];
}
```

Using the above constraint-based code, the soloView's left and top move correctly to full view and back, but when going to full view, the soloView's width and height don't animate and seem to just stay at the destination size. But...it goes back correctly...width and height too.

**Using Frames**

```
- (void) moveToFullView:(NSInteger)which
{
self.soloIndex = which;
NSImageView *tmpView = self.imageviews[which];

self.soloView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:tmpView.frame];
[self.soloView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.soloView.imageScaling = NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown;
self.soloView.image = tmpView.image;

self.soloView.autoresizingMask = NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewWidthSizable;

[self.view addSubview:self.soloView];

[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
    context.duration = 0.75;

    for(NSImageView *p in self.imageviews){
        p.alphaValue = 0;
    }

    self.soloView.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

} completionHandler:nil];
}



- (void) moveBackFromFullView
{
NSRect destR = [self.imageviews[self.soloIndex] frame];

[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
    context.duration = 0.95;

    for(NSImageView *p in self.imageviews){
        p.alphaValue = 1.00;
    }

    self.soloView.frame = destR;

} completionHandler:^{
    [self.soloView removeFromSuperview];
    self.soloView = nil;
}];
}
```

Using the above frame-based code, the soloView animates properly to and from full view, with the correct width and height. But there's something VERY strange when going back...there's another *ghost* view that animates from the origin to the same destination. I have NO idea how there's another animating view. I even checked the number of subviews of self.view and it's 10, but I see 11....the 9 grid views, the soloview and this ghost view. And yes, I have self.view.wantsLayer = YES when the main view is created.

I must be going crazy. Neither code works. I hate working with constraints for such a simple task. I'd rather use the frame based code...it's day and night much simpler, but I have no idea why there's another view moving back.

I have more experience with UIView animation than NSView animation, so maybe I'm missing something fundamental.

ANY help would be very much appreciated.